# How to turn a list of names to initials

Tags: python, list, names

I have a list of names that I need to turn to initials only, so for example ['Surname, Name'] would be NS. This is what I have done so far:

```
list_names = [['Johnson, Sarah'],['Hill, Becky'],['Smith, John']]
for name in list_names:
    for name_string in name:
        split = name_string.split(", ")
        join = " ".join(split)
        initials = ""
        for n in split:
            initials += n[0].upper()
            print(initials)
```

I think it's one of the last steps where I'm going wrong, any help is much appreciated

Edit: I have fixed the typo now, the names were originally in numpy.ndarray which I then turned into the list called list_names

Comment: the first two lists contain a single string separating Name and Surname with a comma, the last list contain two strings with Name and Surname already separated. Is this intended? If so your data structure is inconsistent. Could you provide the desired output for your example?

Comment: One question, do you need 'JS' for 'Johnson, Sarah' or 'SJ'.
If you need JS, you just have to move `print` out of the `for n in split:` loop. If you need `SJ` then you should reverse split before iterating over it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For splitting i have used .split(", ") comma plus space as is it included in the input list.

```
list_names = [['Johnson, Sarah'],['Hill, Becky'],['Smith, John']]
for name in list_names:
    surname,name=name[0].split(', ')
    initials=name[0]+surname[0]
    initials=initials.upper()
    print(initials)
```

I think you want output in this way:

```
SJ
BH
JS
```

Comment: if you want output in list then you can create one list and append the output in that list

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with a list comprehension

```
list_names = [['Johnson, Sarah'],['Hill, Becky'],['Smith, John']]
[f"{i[0].split(',')[1][1]}{i[0].split(',')[0][0]}" for i in list_names]
```

result:

```
['SJ', 'BH', 'JS']
```